# How to enable Maven/Eclipse integration that hyperlinks to compilation errors

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-3

Using eclipse, ANT has built-in integration that zto compilation errors--very handy.

Any way to enable hyperlinked errors on the "Console" tab during "Maven Build..." for Maven 3/M2E and Eclipse 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

With M2 eclipse, if there are compile problems your perspective *should* show you where the errors are in the package explorer as well as problem specifics in the problem view.

Comment: It shows the errors but they are not clickable.  With ANT, you can click on the error and jump to the exact line of code that is failing.  With Maven, it generally doesn't have a hyperlink.  If it does have one, they are not clickable (don't jump to the line of code or even the class).

Comment: Are you using maven under eclipse as an external builder? why? Get m2e (available from eclipse update sites) and convert your project to a maven project in eclipse. When looking at the problem views, you can just double click the errored lines. If you're looking at console output, I'm a little confused then.

Comment: Errors are linkable in the "Problems" tab but some errors only appear when you run as: "Maven build..." or "Maven install"  These errors show up in the "Console" tab and are not hyperlinked the way they are for ANT.

Comment: I see what you are saying now ... Ok sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)?  Among its various features it adds a Maven builder to eclipse.  When you enable Maven dependency management by M2Eclipse on your Eclipse project this builder gets activated.

If you set your project to build automatically (when a change to a file is saved) it will invoke this builder.  It will flag the file(s) in error using Eclipse's error annotation (red asterisk) on the file(s) in the Package Explorer view.

Comment: Is this different than the M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse that ships with 3.7?  Does it show the errors in the "Console" tab or only in the "Problems" tab?

Comment: Hmm.. I knew that M2E was part of the Eclipse project but I didn't know that it _shipped_ with Eclipse 3.7.  Cool.  Since build happens automatically it shows up in the problems view (tab) in addition to highlighting the files in question in the package explorer.  It doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: See my comments above.  Some errors only happen at build time.  For example, I'm useing freemarker which is a templating engine.  it uses tags and if one of these tags are bad it doesn't error until you run build but the error are not hyperlinked.